# How to retrieve values that are not in the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have values in an excel (10 000) value : '8000217', '8000508','8000608', '8000712', '8014705', etc...
and I would like to know if it exists in my table (if it does not exist, I send them out) 
and if it exists not be able to insert the same table

I tried:

```
SELECT Esa 
FROM
    (SELECT 'Test 1' UNION
     SELECT 'Test 2' UNION
     SELECT 'Test 3') [TABLE]
WHERE Esa NOT IN (SELECT Esa FROM[TABLE];
```

but I can not, the request does not work.

I would like the query to return to me those which are not in the SQL table

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you. If you don't want duplicates, however, use a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` or `INDEX`.

Comment: yes update ^^ thx

Comment: That does want explain anything. Where are the values you're looking for that don't exist can't me from ? We need sample data and expected results here to help explain what you're after

Comment: value : '8000217', '8000508','8000608', '8000712', '8014705'

Comment: there are some who are in the table "esa" and other value no, I can recover those who are not in the table

Comment: But you have 2 tables; where's the other table and the expected results?

Comment: I have excel (microsoft) values ​​that I recover, and I want to check if it is in my table and that it returns to me at the exit those which I do not have (1 table)

Comment: You'll need to use something like `OPENQUERY` or `OPENROWSET` to query the worksheet from SQL Server then, and then perform a. `LEFT JOIN` to your table and return rows with a value of `NULL`.

Comment: no we do not care, it's me who takes the values (excel), I just want to check if they are in the table or not
and come out I come back to those who are not in the table

Comment: What do you mean you do not care? If you don't care about the data, why are you doing this at all..?

Comment: the job :/ I just want to check if the values exist or not in the table and that out I have the values that does not exist

Comment: Yes, as I said, use [`OPENROWSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017#distributed-queries) to query the Excel file from SQL server (without the `INTO`) and `LEFT JOIN` to your table. Where there isn't a match, the data is missing.

Comment: you do not understand ^^ it's me who takes the values of the excel file with copy / paste, I would just like some help to make the request, or I put the values and it checks if there is in the table or not and he makes me those who are not there

Answer (score 1):

Use below code with except, it will help to insertion logic

```
SELECT Esa into [TABLE3] from (
    select 'Test 1' as esa union
    select 'Test 2' union
    select 'Test 3' )  [TABLE]
except 
SELECT Esa from (
    select 'Test 1' esa 
    ) [TABLE1]

select * from [TABLE3]

drop table [TABLE3]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have to create a table: /

Comment: So you can remove ```into [TABLE3]```

Answer (score 0):

Since there seems to be a 1-1 cardinality between your data and the target table, yhis looks like a good use case for the `LEFT JOIN` antipattern: try to join the two datasets, and return those that do not match:

```
SELECT Esa 
FROM (
    SELECT 'Test 1' AS Esa UNION ALL SELECT 'Test 2' UNION ALL SELECT 'Test 3'
) [DATA]
LEFT JOIN [TABLE] ON [TABLE].Esa = [DATA].Esa
WHERE [TABLE].Esa IS NULL
```

Another typical option is to use a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXISTS` condition:

```
SELECT Esa 
FROM (
    SELECT 'Test 1' AS Esa 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Test 2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Test 3'
) [DATA]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM [TABLE] WHERE [TABLE].Esa = [DATA].Esa
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  There are a variety of ways to do this.   (untested)

```
declare @ValueToTest int = 8000217

if exists (select 1 from YourTable where ESA = @ValueToTest)
   begin
      print 'It is in the table'
   end
else
   begin
      print 'It is not in the table'
   end
```

Or if you get the values into a table you can left join using where null clause to get values that aren't in the table.

```
select testvalues.ESA
from testvalues
left outer join existingTable on testvalues.ESA = existingTable.ESA
where existingTable.ESA is null
```